# Bottom skewed line with background image and round corners

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a div with a background image which has a skewed bottom AND round corners?

[Most examples](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms) use only a background color which doesn't have the duplicate image problem that a background image has.

**CSS clipping path**

The clipping path option works however, it has [no support on IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

**Closest solution so far**

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="parallelogram">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#parallelogram {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -41px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://baconmockup.com/340/500);
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(11deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(11deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(11deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/81e30bmx/

But the problem with this is that the round corners aren't visible anymore as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `border-radius` to `parent div` could work, as it will work as `border-radius` for `four` corner and then `individually` using `border-top-right-radius, border-top-left-radius,border-bottom-right-radius,border-bottom-left-radius` you can change and align accordingly as below and thus it skews at bottom-left along-with border-radius at 4 sides,

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius:16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:14px;
  border-top-left-radius:40px;
  margin-top:40px;
  display:inline-block;
  }

#parallelogram {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -41px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-11deg);
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 40px;  
}

.image {
  background: url(http://baconmockup.com/340/500);
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(11deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(11deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(11deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="parallelogram">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a static solution this works great! But it's not responsive. If you'd scale it to the browser size, it will break.

Comment: @Remi Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vwr00gma/ scale that back and forth. Actually while scaling that increase and decreases the height of element, thus it breaks the border-radius at some points, so by changing few degree that works fine.

Comment: @fmt Almost there using your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/h7nyvf1b/

Comment: @Remi It works much better. But you could change background-size to cover or 100% 100%.

Comment: That would cause the image to be distorted. Would like to keep the image ratio constraint. For the example I've increased the height of the image. Ideally for a responsive layout, you would have to use different height's for different window widths.

Comment: @Remi you mean could be done using media query. That goes goes upto you as you have planned your layout :-) Happy Coding.

Comment: thanks for the help. For a complete answer, I've adjusted the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/h7nyvf1b/. The trick is in the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Welcome @Remi very nice image transition as I scale it back and forth :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and does seems to work on your example.

If you are talking about the top left and right corners getting chopped off, then what you need to do is add a margin to the top so:

```
#parallelogram { margin: -41px 0 0 0; }
```

Would become:

```
 #parallelogram { margin: 23px 0 0 0; }
```

This will adds the hole shape in.